# Angular - <router-outlet> is not a know element

Tags: angular

I'm writing tests for some module in my project. Sometimes when I run my tests, everything is fine, sometimes I get this errors:
ERROR: 'NG0304: 'soc-reviews-sidebar' is not a known element:

1. If 'soc-reviews-sidebar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'soc-reviews-sidebar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.'
   Chrome Headless 116.0.5845.111 (Windows 10): Executed 295 of 996 SUCCESS (0 secs / 3.19 secs)
   ERROR: 'NG0304: 'soc-reviews-sidebar' is not a known element:
3. If 'soc-reviews-sidebar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
4. If 'soc-reviews-sidebar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this comERROR: 'NG0304: 'router-outlet' is not a known element:
5. If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
6. If 'router-outlet' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.'

This is my .ts file
`import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ClientReviewsModule } from '@reviews/client-reviews/client-reviews.module';
import { ListByServicerComponent } from '@reviews/client-reviews/list-by-servicer/list-by-    servicer.component';
import { ReviewsSidebarComponent } from '@reviews/reviews-sidebar/reviews-sidebar.component';
import { ReviewsComponent } from '@reviews/reviews.component';
import { ReviewsService } from '@reviews/service/reviews.service';
import { ReceivedComponent } from '@reviews/servicer-reviews/received/received.component';
import { ServicerReviewsModule } from '@reviews/servicer-reviews/servicer-reviews.module';
import { SharedModule } from '@shared/shared.module';
import { TokenInterceptor } from 'src/app/token-interceptor/token-interceptor';

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ReviewsComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'received'
      },
      {
        path: 'received',
        component: ReceivedComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'left',
        component: ListByServicerComponent
      }
    ]
  }
 ];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ReviewsComponent, ReviewsSidebarComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    ClientReviewsModule,
    ServicerReviewsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
   ],
   exports: [ReviewsComponent],
   providers: [
    ReviewsService,
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: TokenInterceptor, multi: true }
  ]
})
export class ReviewsModule {}`
```

And this is my spec.ts file:
`import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { ReviewsComponent } from '@reviews/reviews.component';
import { ReviewsSidebarComponent } from './reviews-sidebar/reviews-sidebar.component';

```
describe('ReviewsComponent', () => {
  let component: ReviewsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ReviewsComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ReviewsComponent, ReviewsSidebarComponent],
      imports: [RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([])]
    }).compileComponents();
   });

   beforeEach(() => {
     fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ReviewsComponent);
     component = fixture.componentInstance;
   });

  afterEach(() => {
    fixture.destroy();
  });
});`
```

So, as I can guess, I imported ReviewsSidebarComponent and RouterTestingModule. I tried also to import routes to my spec files but same happens again.

Comment: If this is your main definition of `RouterModule` use `RouterModule.forRoot(...)`

Comment: I'm not sure what are you asking. This is not my app.module.ts . This is one of the modules of my app

Comment: Replace `RouterModule.forChild(routes)` with `forRoot.forChild(routes)`. `ForChild` is only use when you declare more routes inside a child route.

Comment: I'm not sure what are you saying to me. Should I replace it in app.module.ts or in spec files?

Comment: In `app.module.ts`,  but ultimately in both...

Answer (score 0):

Add `RouterModule` in `exports` array too in `module.ts`

```js
exports: [RouterModule]
```

Comment: To spec.ts or .ts file ?

Comment: in module.ts file like reviews.module.ts

Comment: Still, same happens

Answer (score 0):

You have to add AppRoutingModule to your imports in app.module.ts, like this:

```
imports: [AppRoutingModule, ...]
```

You find your app.module.ts next to the other app. files:

[image]

Let me know if it worked.

Hands up for Angular.

Comment: I dont have app.routing.module.ts. In my app.module.ts I have declared routes

Comment: I added an image of the file structure, this is how it should look like and where you find your app.module.ts

Comment: Im not sure if you get me. I don't have app-routing.module.ts. I do it directly in app.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I wasn't imported Reviews module correctly to some other module (Tasks module). Thank you all for trying to help me.